# Find all possible combinations of variables for linear model with interactions and their subsets in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, combinations

This is a close cousin to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71854995/linear-model-calculate-all-possible-combinations-of-variables-with-interaction). However, I'm looking for a way to efficiently create formulas that also include *subsets of possible interactions*. For example, the answer using `combn()` produces the output

`y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x1:x2 + x1:x3 + x2:x3 + x1:x2:x3`

as well as

`y ~ x1 + x2 + x4 + x1:x2 + x1:x4 + x2:x4 + x1:x2:x4`, among other combinations.

I am also looking to get the result

`y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x1:x2`

`y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x1:x3`

`y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x1:x2 + x1:x3`

and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: how many variables do you have in your use case

Comment: I only have 5 independent variables, so thankfully not too many. However, I need to run this same process for 4 different dependent variables.

Comment: ok and are you only going up to 3-way interactions?

Comment: I theory, yes, but my analysis is a little exploratory, so I don’t want to miss potential interactions for that reason. 

Here’s the background: I’m analyzing exercise testing data and using algorithms to find two “thresholds”. I hypothesized these algorithms are sensitive to prior steps of outlier removal and data averaging. I’m using different combos of algorithm, outlier, and averaging methods to find these thresholds. Those three variables likely contain the extent of the interactions. I also have controlling vars of age and sex, and possibly and interaction between those two.